# Misleading ERROR: relation [“schema_name.table_name”] does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Should not it be `ERROR: relation [“schema name”].["table_name"] does not exist` instead? Lots of people use case sensitive relation names with dots and so forth. Eg:

```
t=# select * from public.t1;
ERROR:  relation "public.t1" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from public.t1;
                      ^
t=# create table "public.t1" (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# select * from public.t1;
ERROR:  relation "public.t1" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from public.t1;
```

I am used to getting this error so much that I did not notice that it is misleading. And yet today I hit it with `relation.name` and realized that error should not use double quotes like this. Is it intentional or should I address it as a bug?

Comment: I would consider it a _bug_, because the message is misleading.

Comment: Have you tried `select * from "public.t1"` *before* creating `"public.t1"` What is the message in that case? What is your proposed alternative? And why are you discussing this here rather than on an appropriate PostgreSQL community site?

Comment: @AndriyM `"public.t1"` does not exist. I ask here before going to Pg comunity, because I could just miss some obvious point

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a table with a dot identifier.

```
CREATE TABLE "public.t1" ( a int );
\d public.t1
Did not find any relation named "public.t1".
```

But, then if you quote it again there..

```
\d "public.t1"
   Table "public.public.t1"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 a      | integer | 

SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE '%t1%';
 table_catalog | table_schema | table_name 
---------------+--------------+------------
 test          | public       | public.t1
```

So instead use this if you want to be goofy,

```
SELECT * FROM "public.t1";
```

Or, simply [*never* quote identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

> Quoted identifiers can contain any character other than a double quote itself. (To include a double quote, write two double quotes.) This allows **constructing table or column names that would otherwise not be possible, such as ones containing spaces or ampersands.** The length limitation still applies.

And, also periods.

This is agianst the convention of PostgreSQL. Unless you're doing something *like* an automated migration that needs to avoid collisions, I would higly suggest you avoid *quoted identifiers* entirely.

- Always create things unquoted.
- Always references things unquoted.

It's not just special characters either. Quoted identifiers make your schema caps-sensitive. This can make your life needlessly more difficult.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I understand why I get this error. What I'm saying that `ERROR:  relation "public.t1" does not exist` should be `ERROR:  relation "public"."t1" does not exist` when I `select 1 from public.t1`. And I'm asking - is it misleading only to me?

Comment: That's not even a question. You're just polling people?

Comment: @VaoTsun Yes, I agree. It could be clearer. But, write to hackers and tell them. That message should be unquoted unless quotes are needed. I would suggest wrapping it in something other than quotes. That said, this is *totally* off platform here.

Comment: I asked if it is a feature or a bug before reporting it to comunity. I hoped the question was about DBA and could be answered. Sorry If I messed up here.

Comment: There are thousands of areas where things could be clearer. It's a good suggestion. It could be better. But, it's not "a bug." An error occurred and it's trying to communicate that error with you.

Comment: Yes. I've got an answer from pg community yet. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20170117110918.1434.14259%40wrigleys.postgresql.org